# how to read another javascript JSON categories

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web

I have no idea how to make this,

I have a **loop for** product List Item, but i really don't know how to link the **shop item** to **shop name**. I have tried many method but i really don't know how to link the item to the shop.

if `productList.ShopId` = `shopList.id` then use this `shopList.title`
SHOP NAME = `shopList.title`

```
const getProductList = function (productItem) {
    const productListRender = 
    $('<div>').append($('<span>', {
        html: shopName() <<<< SHOP NAME
    }));

    $.each(data.shopList), function shopName() {
        this.text(shopList.title);
    };
        
    return productListRender;
}
const $product = $('#List')
$.each(data.productList, function (index, data) {
    $product.append(getProductList(data));
});
```

Data JS is Below:

```
var data = {
    productList: [
        {
            id: "62276197-6059-4c21-9b40-c5b1d277e85d",
            link: "javascript:void(0)",
            imgurl: "/img/upload/png/joyacart_000001_12032019.png",
            text: 'Product 001',
            goldMedal: false,
            newItem: true,
            newShop: true,
            freeDelivery: true,
            ShopId: '5cfb048c-86e8-4d2d-85bf-e4e9e1effdcb'
        },
        {
            id: "59de8216-052d-4e51-9f7d-7e96642ded62",
            link: "javascript:void(0)",
            imgurl: "/img/upload/png/joyacart_000002_12032019.png",
            text: 'Product 002',
            goldMedal: true,
            newItem: false,
            newShop: true,
            freeDelivery: true,
            ShopId: '10eb4250-47d6-41ad-a429-f65e05836f26'
        },
        {
            id: "59de8216-052d-4e51-9f7d-7e96642ded62",
            link: "javascript:void(0)",
            imgurl: "/img/upload/png/joyacart_000003_12032019.png",
            text: 'Product 003',
            goldMedal: true,
            newItem: false,
            newShop: true,
            freeDelivery: true,
            ShopId: '10eb4250-47d6-41ad-a429-f65e05836f26'
        }],

    shopList: [{
        id: '5cfb048c-86e8-4d2d-85bf-e4e9e1effdcb',
        title: 'Shop 001'
    },
    {
        id: '10eb4250-47d6-41ad-a429-f65e05836f26',
        title: 'Test Shop'
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refine `shopName` as:

```js
function shopName(shopId) {
  // find the right shop by comparing shopId with each `shop.id`
  // uses optional chaining to prevent errors
  // returns undefineds if no match is found
  return shopList.filter(shop => shop.id === shopId)?.[0]?.title;
}

const shopList = [{
    id: '5cfb048c-86e8-4d2d-85bf-e4e9e1effdcb',
    title: 'Shop 001'
  },
  {
    id: '10eb4250-47d6-41ad-a429-f65e05836f26',
    title: 'Test Shop'
  }]

console.log(shopName('10eb4250-47d6-41ad-a429-f65e05836f26'));
console.log(shopName('222'));
```

Answer (score 1):

everything seems to be in order in your data. only thing that i can see is that there was some mishap in your comparison method.
have you tried comparing them not with equal sign but rather treat them as string .

you could see this link for reference..

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-compare-two-strings-in-JavaScript